# Upload APNs certificate to AWS Lambda

Tags: django, aws-lambda, apple-push-notifications, zappa

I am using Django with Zappa to connect to serverless AWS Lambda. To get APNs (Apple Push Notification services) up and running, I originally had to upload my certificate file to the server, so that my backend can access it whenever it needs to. But now that I migrated to AWS Lambda, I am not sure how to upload the certificate file.

I use this package [django-push-notifications](https://github.com/jazzband/django-push-notifications) to use APNs and in my Django settings, I have

`PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_SETTINGS = {
        "APNS_CERTIFICATE": os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "../../Certificates_and_keys/prod_pushcert.pem"),
        "APNS_TOPIC": "org.reactjs.native.example.Spap",
        "UPDATE_ON_DUPLICATE_REG_ID": True,
        "USER_MODEL": "social.User",
}`

Where the value for APNS_CERTIFICATE is the path of the APNs certificate file. Before using AWS Lambda, I had another server where I uploaded the certificate file with ftp. I don't know how to do that with AWS Lambda. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know off the top of my head how long APNs certificates are, but if they're [less than 4 KB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html), then you could add it as a Lambda environment variable and read it into a temporary file on startup (in `settings.py`).

If they're larger than 4 KB, you could store the certificate in S3 and then download it to a temporary file on startup:

```py
import boto3
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

s3 = boto3.client("s3")

with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
    s3.download_fileobj("mybucket", "mykey", f)

APNS_CERTIFICATE = f.name
```

(Disclaimer: I haven't tested this exact code)

This could get expensive, though, because you're fetching the file from S3 every time the Lambda is invoked. Zappa's `keep_warm` feature might help with this, but I'm not completely sure how it works so take that with a grain of salt.

You'll probably also want to disable this unless `DEBUG` or another indicator that you're developing locally is set, so you don't try to fetch your production APNs cert during development.

Comment: It's actually just above 4KB. How about just hardcoding the contents of the certificate file into my settings.py, can I do that? Have the string hardcoded, store it into a temporary file and use the file path? I'm going to try that.

Comment: @RonyAzrak I wouldn't recommend that, especially if the code is going to be open-sourced – I believe the APNs certificate is the only thing needed to send notifications to users of your app, so it would be pretty bad if it was compromised.

Answer (score 1):

Certificates need to be handled in `us-east-1` region (N. Virginia) through the AWS console under *Certificate Manager* service. Other regions won't work.

There you have the option to *Import a certificate*.

After you have the certificate there, you can use `boto3` to read it and use it in your code. For code example please see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-acm-get_certificate.py.html